# Can I use specific method for dependency injection in ejb?

Tags: java, ejb

For example I have a class that gets a dependecy in constructor, like

```java
class ExampleService() {

    private Dependency dep;

    public ExampleService(Dependency dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

}
```

and Dependecy class:

```
class Dependency {

    public static Dependency getInstance() {
        return new Dependency();
    }

    private Dependency() {
        /*constructor implementation here*/
    }

}
```

I want to inject result of Dependency.getInstance() method into ExampleService constructor by @Inject EJB annotation. Is it possible? How? Thankyou.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just singleton-scope your `Dependency` bean instead of trying to make it a code-based singleton?

Comment: @chrylis there is no reason. I'm a newbie and read about this scope right now. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CDI a producer method [can be static](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/inject/Produces.html), so using your example, the following would work just fine:

```
class ExampleService() {

    private Dependency dep;

    @Inject
    public ExampleService(Dependency dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

}

class Dependency {

    @Produces
    public static Dependency getInstance() {
        return new Dependency();
    }

    private Dependency() {
       /*constructor implementation here*/
    }

}
```

However, like mentioned in the comments to your question, there might be better ways depending on what you want.